# Nginx Special folder to another directiry

Tags: php, linux, apache, nginx

I have a special path in my site that should read files from another directory in my server.

```
 server {
  server_name www.translation1010.com translation1010.com;

    root /var/www/translation1010.com/;


    error_log /var/www/translation1010.com/_error.log;
  index index.php;



  #include /etc/nginx/options;

}
```

i want 
translation1010.com/admin/ 
read from 
**/var/www/admins.com/panel/**

what code should i use in ngnix?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
server {
  server_name www.translation1010.com translation1010.com;

  error_log /var/www/translation1010.com/_error.log;
  index index.php;
  location / {
     root /var/www/translation1010.com/;
  }

  location /admin/ {
     root /var/www/admins.com/panel/;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx but this didn't work... with this code even main domain don't work right and show 404 page

Comment: @computer2000  make sure error log file exists in `/var/www/translation1010.com/_error.log`

Answer (score -1):

make sure /admin location in front of /

recommended to use alias, it direct pointing to /var/www/admins.com/panel/ instead of /var/www/admins.com/panel/admin

```
 server {
  server_name www.translation1010.com translation1010.com;
  location /admin/ {
     alias /var/www/admins.com/panel/;
  }
  location / {
     alias /var/www/translation1010.com/;
  }
  error_log /var/www/translation1010.com/_error.log;
  index index.php;

}
```

Comment: i found that it works without include option file but download php file except execute...

Comment: @computer2000 you need to execute index.php with php service,and then proxy_pass it with nginx